# How to change the log level properties in Talend open studio 7.1.1

Tags: talend, data-integration

I am Trying to set the log level for my Data Integration job in Talend studio version 7.1.1 to "Warn". Looks like the option is no longer available in Run --> Advanced Settings. How do I change log levels in talend 7.1.1? Please clarify. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try looking under File, Project settings, Log4j. You should be able to customise the level of the logs there.